# code stuck in while loop, not posting anything

Tags: python, while-loop

i am new to python. I ve been working on this mini exercise for school.[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5lUQ.png)

its baisically about seeing how many times a number is repeated in every row.
my main problem is that when i run the code nothing happens and i the green "re run button" and a red square stop button when pressed it spits this error :

*Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Mega-PC\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\main.py", line 8, in 
while not(h!=len(a[i])):
KeyboardInterrupt*

is there something wrong with my reasoning? what can i do to fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please do not post screenshots of code. PLease post the actual code. Its faster than doing the scrren shot and it means others can test your code and post corrected version in answers

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

While the while loop is running, nothing changes the value of h, or the length of a[i].